# Annotation-based interceptors on EJBs

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, interceptor

Is it possible to declare interceptors on EJBs using interceptor-binding-able annotations, like we do on CDI beans?

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@InterceptorBinding
public @interface MyInterceptor {
}

@Stateless
@Remote(MyService.class)
public MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

     @Override
     @MyInterceptor
     public String myBusinessMethod() {
          return "";
     }

}
```

Comment: Not only it's possible but also recommended way of doing. What's blocking you from simply trying it?

Comment: I don't know why but it doesn't seem to work on JBoss 7.0. I'm still investigating. I find it ugly when `@Interceptors(MyInterceptor.class`.

Comment: Now working, after adding `@Priority`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can treat the EJBs almost like any other CDI bean. You need to either activate the interceptors in the beans.xml or add an @Interceptor binding. See the weld documentation for more information https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/interceptors.html

The standard EJB annotations are implemented like this as well, as can be seen in the src or the above mentioned documenation link.